# jQuery remove / append event handler callback

Tags: jquery, callback

I have a event handler that runs when a UL has children LI appended or removed.

In the case of appending, the callback is after the element is appended, which is what I want.

But, in the case of removal, the callback is executed before the element is removed. This means the callback only has access to the old UL and not the new UL after the element is removed.

I've outputted the UL in the callback, and indeed it is the UL prior to having an element removed. I want the callback to work with the UL after the element has been removed. One can see evidence of this in the length of the list outputted.

http://jsfiddle.net/n9KYF/

HTML:

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>

<button id="removeButton">Remove Element</button>
<button id="appendButton">Append Element</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // removes the last element
    $("#removeButton").click(function() {
        var items = $("#myList").children();
        var lastIndex = items.length - 1;
        if (lastIndex < 0) {
            alert("nothing to remove");
        } else {
            items.eq(lastIndex).remove();
        } 
    });

    // append a list item
    $("#appendButton").click(function() {
        var itemNumber = $("#myList").children().length;
        var ch = String.fromCharCode(97 + itemNumber);

        $("#myList").append("<li>" + ch + "</li>");
    });

    // event handler when the list is changed
    // element not removed until AFTER this callback executed, how can
    // suppress execution of this callback until after element removed
    $(document.getElementById("myList")).bind("DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved", function() {

        alert("Num Children : " + $(this).children().length);

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is true that `DOMNodeRemoved` is fired before the removal. However, it is not a bad thing, because you can get the element that is being removed from `event.target`.

```
$(document.getElementById("myList")).bind("DOMNodeInserted DOMNodeRemoved", function(e) {
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

Comment: So what I want to do is get the parent of that target, as if the target has been removed. Let's call parent_post the parent after  removal and parent_pre the parent prior to removal (which is what I can access from the callback).  Is there any elegant way to get parent_post? Other than doing parent_pre "subtract" target, to get something === to parent_post?

Answer (score 0):

DOMNodeRemoved is fired BEFORE the script is going to remove an item. Read the official description here:

[w3c.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) (You have to scroll down a little):

Quote:

> DOMNodeRemoved
>       Fired when a node is being removed from its parent node. **This event is dispatched before the node is removed from the tree**. The target of this event is the node being removed.

```
    Bubbles: Yes
    Cancelable: No
    Context Info: relatedNode holds the parent node
```

As *Fabricator* wrote it before i could finish my post ( ;) ), the event.target helps you getting your removed item.